# How to create a counter map in reactive programming?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

The only solution I came up with is to use a `groupBy` but it looks hacky, IMO:

```
objectsObservable
                .groupBy(object -> object)
                .flatMapMaybe(sameObjectsObservable -> {
                    Object object = sameObjectsObservable.getKey();
                    return sameObjectsObservable
                            .count()
                            .filter(shouldFilter)
                            .ignoreElement()
                            .andThen(Maybe.just(object));

                })
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the one step to `count()` the individual group.

```
objectsObservable
  .groupBy( object -> object )
  .flatMap( objectGroup -> objectGroup
                             .count()
                             .map( c -> objectGroup.getKey() + " has " + c + " elements") )
  .subscribe( System::out::println );
```